# why does binary search while loop condition ( l+1 != u)?

Tags: algorithm

```
a = (1..10).to_a
def search(x, t)
  l = -1
  u = x.length

  while l+1 != u
    m = (l + u) / 2.round
    if x[m] < t
      l = m
    else
      u = m
    end
    puts "l:\t#{l} u:\t #{u} m:\t#{m}"
  end

  p = u
  puts "p: #{p} -> #{x[p]}"
  if p >= x.length || x[p] != t
    p = -1
  end
end

search(a, 5)
```

i was research long times , but can't found the why,

1. l = -1

   > why initial assign the l to -1
2. while loop condition why is `l+1 != u` than `l < u`

i'm trying to understand that method ,finally can't eat it

can does help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**l** and **u** are lower and upper of your binary search.

Here you are assigning **l** to -1 and **u** to x.length. You can easily change the assignment of **l** from -1 to 0, and change the condition **l+1 != u** to **l < u**.

Comment: yes, right, condition quite can be `l < u` but i'm looking for book, in which `l+1 != u` this is invariance ` l < t <= u`

Comment: l+1 != u seems incorrect to me as you can jump past the meeting point of l and u and keep running.

Comment: <<programming pearls 2>>

Comment: it's change invariance `x[l] < t <= x[u] && l < u`

Comment: also, you're not breaking when you actually find your number?

Comment: the while condition `l+1 != u`, finally actual it's break, also `l + 1 = u`, i'm trying a lot of times

Comment: try to dry run your code on this sample array: [2 4 5 7 8 9] and search for number 5. It should find it in first run, but it keeps iterating till l+1 != u which is not nice, until you want to find multiple matches.

Comment: oh, all right, it's excellent, it is important that in which would be keeping iterating until `l+1 1= u`  be match , haha,  thanks

Comment: this way quite some not nice for efficiency.